# How to continiously read data change from firebase realtime database in vue.js

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, vuejs2, vue-component

I am using vue.js version 2 with cdn mode. I have created 2 vue components. One components is pushing the data to database and the other component will show it. Below is the code

```js
firebase.database().ref().on('value', function (data) {
      console.log("called");
      console.log("data received " + JSON.stringify(data));
    });
```

I want to read data continuously, but above method is not working. It reads the data only one time. How to solve this issue so that I can read the data continuously ?

Comment: yes. one index.html page is there I am using the v-if directive to activate deactivate the section of publisher and consumer

Comment: Don't know much about realtime firebase, but the sample apps seem to use `firestore`, like `firebase.firestore().collection('foo').limit(1).onSnapshot(function(snapshot) { some_code });` for realtime reads - [example web app](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/tree/master/firestore)

Answer (score 0):

I have done this in vue like this

```
import {  onValue,  ref as Ref} from "firebase/database";

onValue(Ref(db, path), (snapshot) => {
         // you get value here
         //snapshot.val());
    });

// where db is the main Database reference
// and path is the path inside db
```

Comment: actually its cdn based so this approach might not work since above code format looks like the .vue file format

Comment: it is in typescript (you can port it into javascript as well).. so I believe it should work